# In Test class no result for Order.Account.RecordTypeId

Tags: apex, unit-test, child-to-parent

In a test class, I want to update Account information depending on the record type. The information to update comes from the Order object. I have created a test account with the according record type. In the test factory, the Account creation looks like this:

```
    public static Account createNewsletterRecipientAccount(){
       RecordType personAccountRecordType =  [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE 
          Name = 'Newsletter' and SObjectType = 'Account'];
       Account mockAccount = new Account();
       mockAccount.FirstName = 'Hans';
       mockAccount.AccountNumber = '1';
       mockAccount.LastName = 'Meier';
       mockAccount.EXT_Id__c = 'testExtId';
       mockAccount.RecordType = personAccountRecordType;
       mockAccount.RecordType.Name = 'Newsletter';
       return mockAccount;
}
```

In the test, I call the class as follows:

```
Account account = MockUpFactory.createNewsletterRecipientAccount();
insert account;
```

When I do a debug here, I do get the Record Type 'Newsletter' for the Account. Then I create the Orders for the test:

```
list <Order> listOrders = new list <Order>();
for(Integer i=0; i<10; i++){
  Order order = new Order(); 
  order.AccountId = account.Id;
  order.EffectiveDate = Date.today().addDays(-i);
  listOrders.add(order);
}
insert listOrders;
```

When I do a debug here for listOrders[0].Account.RecordTypeId, I get null as a result. How would I have to write the code so that I get a proper result for the RecordTypeId?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My assumption you need the record type Id for the Newsletter. And while creating an account you need to tag recordtypeid field

Check this:

```
Id recordTypeId =  [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE 
          DeveloperName = 'Newsletter' and SObjectType = 'Account' LIMIT 1].id;
```

While creating a test account mention

```
mockAccount.RecordTypeId = recordTypeId;
```

Comment: Yes, I replaced these two lines:    mockAccount.RecordType = personAccountRecordType;   mockAccount.RecordType.Name = 'Newsletter'; with this line: mockAccount.RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Newsletter Empfänger').getRecordTypeId();     THIS WORKED!